# MySQL left join query suddenly hangs in one db but runs in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL that lists out articles with connected prices using left join to get the newest price. Suddenly this query is starting to hang when I try to run it. If I remove the left join, and do an regular join, it runs at normal speed. But then I don't get the desired result

The thing is that it usually runs just fine. And when I do an Explain everything looks ok. I even have an older database with the same tables and indexes, and if I run it there, it finishes in 1.5 seconds. The only difference is that the data is a bit older.

I have indexes.

So where do I start to debug? I have checked for damaged tables, and run repair table just to be sure. Even restarted the server. What else is there to check?

It's running on an Ubuntu server 14.04.5, and MySQL-version is 5.6.22 and I use PHP to connect to the database.

```
SELECT a.art_id AS art_id, a.ecs_id AS ecs_id, a.parent_id AS parent_id, a.primarytext AS primarytext, a.serie AS serie, a.receipttext AS receipttext,
a.postername AS postername, a.posterdescription AS posterdescription, a. primarysupplier AS primarysupplier, a.ean1 AS ean1, a.supplierarticleno AS supplierarticleno,
a.dropdate AS dropdate, a.salesinfo AS salesinfo, a.packagesize,
sp.price AS utpris, sp.fromdate AS utprisFromdate, sp.todate AS utprisTodate, pp.price AS innpris, pp.fromdate AS innprisFromdate, pp.todate AS innprisTodate

FROM ecs_article AS a
LEFT JOIN ecs_purchaseprice pp ON a.art_id=pp.article_id
LEFT JOIN ecs_saleprice sp ON a.art_id=sp.article_id
WHERE a.primarysupplier='HK'
AND a.dropdate > now()
AND (a.art_id LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.primarytext LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.serie LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.parent_id LIKE '%new connection%')
AND ( sp.fromdate = (
SELECT max(fromdate)
from ecs_saleprice y
where y.article_id=sp.article_id
)
OR sp.fromdate IS NULL
)
AND ( pp.fromdate = (
SELECT max(fromdate)
from ecs_purchaseprice yp
where yp.article_id=pp.article_id
)
OR pp.fromdate IS NULL

)
GROUP BY a.art_id
ORDER BY a.art_id
```

This is the result of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type        table   type  possible_keys       key            key_len     ref             rows Extra  
1   PRIMARY            a       range supDropDateIndex    supDropDateIndex   38      NULL            2257 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY            pp      ref   artIdFromdateIndex  artIdFromdateIndex 767     a.art_id        4    Using where
1   PRIMARY            sp      ref   spartididx          spartididx         26      a.art_id        5    Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY yp      ref   artIdFromdateIndex  artIdFromdateIndex 767     pp.article_id   4    Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY y       ref   spartididx          spartididx         26      sp.article_id   5    Using where
```

EDIT: I have rephrased the question and removed som stuff from the query that doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Do we have a privilege to see that query ??

Comment: Yes, I've added the query. But I don't think the query in itself is the issue.

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN for the old and new databases? Your string comparisons (LIKE '%new connection%') likely are very sensitive to the number of records in ecs_article, so if the old database has 100 rows, and the new has 100000, that would be a likely cause.

Comment: The number of records is about the same. ~117000 in old database, and ~118000 in new database. I use phpmyadmin, it's a bit hard to format the output from the Explain in a nice way, but they are really very similar. For the new DB it is:
a:  2258 rows
pp: 4 rows
sp: 5 rows
yp: 4 rows
y: 5 rows
and all of the artprops are 1 row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having over 30 sub queries in the SELECT statement is quite likely going to cause issues, especially if the number of rows returned increases. Add the 2 sub queries in the WHERE clause and there are major potential issues

If you have 100k rows on the ecs_article table you could easily be forcing SQL to perform over 3m queries internally to return your result set. A massive number that increases with the rows returned.

You also have a GROUP BY without using any aggregate function.

I would suggest using sub queries if necessary. Not tested but something like the following. This is coping with multiple records for each key on the ecs_artprops table.

```
SELECT a.art_id AS art_id, 
        a.ecs_id AS ecs_id, 
        a.parent_id AS parent_id, 
        a.primarytext AS primarytext, 
        a.serie AS serie, 
        a.receipttext AS receipttext,
        a.postername AS postername, 
        a.posterdescription AS posterdescription, 
        a. primarysupplier AS primarysupplier, 
        a.ean1 AS ean1, 
        a.supplierarticleno AS supplierarticleno,
        a.dropdate AS dropdate, 
        a.salesinfo AS salesinfo, 
        a.packagesize,
        sp.price AS utpris, 
        sp.fromdate AS utprisFromdate, 
        sp.todate AS utprisTodate, 
        pp.price AS innpris, 
        pp.fromdate AS innprisFromdate, 
        pp.todate AS innprisTodate, 
        ECS_Height_sub.value AS ECS_Height, 
        ECS_Width_sub.value AS ECS_Width, 
        ECS_Length_sub.value AS ECS_Length, 
        ECS_Depth_sub.value AS ECS_Depth, 
        ECS_Depth2_sub.value AS ECS_Depth2, 
        ECS_Diameter_sub.value AS ECS_Diameter, 
        ECS_Space_sub.value AS ECS_Space, 
        ECS_Seatdepth_sub.value AS ECS_Seatdepth, 
        ECS_Seatheight_sub.value AS ECS_Seatheight, 
        ECS_Bedsize_sub.value AS ECS_Bedsize, 
        ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.value AS ECS_SurfaceTreat, 
        ECS_Weight_sub.value AS ECS_Weight, 
        ECS_Volume_sub.value AS ECS_Volume, 
        ECS_Doors_sub.value AS ECS_Doors, 
        ECS_Shelfs_sub.value AS ECS_Shelfs, 
        ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.value AS ECS_Extensionleaves, 
        ECS_Dropleaves_sub.value AS ECS_Dropleaves, 
        ECS_Drawers_sub.value AS ECS_Drawers, 
        ECS_Other_sub.value AS ECS_Other, 
        ECS_Unit_sub.value AS ECS_Unit, 
        ECS_Brand_sub.value AS ECS_Brand, 
        ECS_Colour_sub.value AS ECS_Colour, 
        ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.value AS ECS_DeliveryTime, 
        ECS_Material_sub.value AS ECS_Material, 
        ECS_Mechanism_sub.value AS ECS_Mechanism, 
        ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.value AS ECS_AssemblyPrice, 
        ECS_Assembled_sub.value AS ECS_Assembled, 
        ECS_Cushion_sub.value AS ECS_Cushion, 
        ECS_Manufacturer_sub.value AS ECS_Manufacturer, 
        ECS_FabricNeed_sub.value AS ECS_FabricNeed, 
        ECS_Size_sub.value AS ECS_Size
FROM ecs_article AS a
LEFT JOIN ecs_purchaseprice pp ON a.art_id=pp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_saleprice sp ON a.art_id=sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_saleprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_sale
ON sub_max_fromdate_sale.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_purchaseprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_purchase
ON sub_max_fromdate_purchase.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Height' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Height_sub  ON ECS_Height_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Width' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Width_sub    ON ECS_Width_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Length' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Length_sub  ON ECS_Length_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Depth' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Depth_sub    ON ECS_Depth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Depth2' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Depth2_sub  ON ECS_Depth2_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Diameter' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Diameter_sub  ON ECS_Diameter_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Space' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Space_sub    ON ECS_Space_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Seatdepth' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Seatdepth_sub    ON ECS_Seatdepth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Seatheight' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Seatheight_sub  ON ECS_Seatheight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Bedsize' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Bedsize_sub    ON ECS_Bedsize_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_SurfaceTreat' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub  ON ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Weight' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Weight_sub  ON ECS_Weight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Volume' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Volume_sub  ON ECS_Volume_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Doors' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Doors_sub    ON ECS_Doors_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Shelfs' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Shelfs_sub  ON ECS_Shelfs_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Extensionleaves' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Extensionleaves_sub    ON ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Dropleaves' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Dropleaves_sub  ON ECS_Dropleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Drawers' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Drawers_sub    ON ECS_Drawers_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Other' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Other_sub    ON ECS_Other_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Unit' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Unit_sub  ON ECS_Unit_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Brand' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Brand_sub    ON ECS_Brand_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Colour' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Colour_sub  ON ECS_Colour_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_DeliveryTime' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_DeliveryTime_sub  ON ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Material' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Material_sub  ON ECS_Material_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Mechanism' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Mechanism_sub    ON ECS_Mechanism_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_AssemblyPrice' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub    ON ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Assembled' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Assembled_sub    ON ECS_Assembled_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Cushion' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Cushion_sub    ON ECS_Cushion_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Manufacturer' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Manufacturer_sub  ON ECS_Manufacturer_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_FabricNeed' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_FabricNeed_sub  ON ECS_FabricNeed_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT art_id, MAX(value) FROM ecs_artprops WHERE prop_id='ECS_Size' GROUP BY art_id) AS ECS_Size_sub  ON ECS_Size_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id
WHERE a.primarysupplier='HK'
AND a.dropdate > now()
AND (a.art_id LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.primarytext LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.serie LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.parent_id LIKE '%new connection%')
AND ( sp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_sale.max_fromdate
OR sp.fromdate IS NULL)
AND ( pp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_purchase.max_fromdate
OR pp.fromdate IS NULL)
ORDER BY a.art_id
```

If there are multi records but not many it might be easier to use this:-

```
SELECT a.art_id AS art_id, 
        a.ecs_id AS ecs_id, 
        a.parent_id AS parent_id, 
        a.primarytext AS primarytext, 
        a.serie AS serie, 
        a.receipttext AS receipttext,
        a.postername AS postername, 
        a.posterdescription AS posterdescription, 
        a. primarysupplier AS primarysupplier, 
        a.ean1 AS ean1, 
        a.supplierarticleno AS supplierarticleno,
        a.dropdate AS dropdate, 
        a.salesinfo AS salesinfo, 
        a.packagesize,
        sp.price AS utpris, 
        sp.fromdate AS utprisFromdate, 
        sp.todate AS utprisTodate, 
        pp.price AS innpris, 
        pp.fromdate AS innprisFromdate, 
        pp.todate AS innprisTodate, 
        MAX(ECS_Height_sub.values) AS ECS_Height, 
        MAX(ECS_Width_sub.values) AS ECS_Width, 
        MAX(ECS_Length_sub.values) AS ECS_Length, 
        MAX(ECS_Depth_sub.values) AS ECS_Depth, 
        MAX(ECS_Depth2_sub.values) AS ECS_Depth2, 
        MAX(ECS_Diameter_sub.values) AS ECS_Diameter, 
        MAX(ECS_Space_sub.values) AS ECS_Space, 
        MAX(ECS_Seatdepth_sub.values) AS ECS_Seatdepth, 
        MAX(ECS_Seatheight_sub.values) AS ECS_Seatheight, 
        MAX(ECS_Bedsize_sub.values) AS ECS_Bedsize, 
        MAX(ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.values) AS ECS_SurfaceTreat, 
        MAX(ECS_Weight_sub.values) AS ECS_Weight, 
        MAX(ECS_Volume_sub.values) AS ECS_Volume, 
        MAX(ECS_Doors_sub.values) AS ECS_Doors, 
        MAX(ECS_Shelfs_sub.values) AS ECS_Shelfs, 
        MAX(ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.values) AS ECS_Extensionleaves, 
        MAX(ECS_Dropleaves_sub.values) AS ECS_Dropleaves, 
        MAX(ECS_Drawers_sub.values) AS ECS_Drawers, 
        MAX(ECS_Other_sub.values) AS ECS_Other, 
        MAX(ECS_Unit_sub.values) AS ECS_Unit, 
        MAX(ECS_Brand_sub.values) AS ECS_Brand, 
        MAX(ECS_Colour_sub.values) AS ECS_Colour, 
        MAX(ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.values) AS ECS_DeliveryTime, 
        MAX(ECS_Material_sub.values) AS ECS_Material, 
        MAX(ECS_Mechanism_sub.values) AS ECS_Mechanism, 
        MAX(ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.values) AS ECS_AssemblyPrice, 
        MAX(ECS_Assembled_sub.values) AS ECS_Assembled, 
        MAX(ECS_Cushion_sub.values) AS ECS_Cushion, 
        MAX(ECS_Manufacturer_sub.values) AS ECS_Manufacturer, 
        MAX(ECS_FabricNeed_sub.values) AS ECS_FabricNeed, 
        MAX(ECS_Size_sub.values) AS ECS_Size
FROM ecs_article AS a
LEFT JOIN ecs_purchaseprice pp ON a.art_id=pp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_saleprice sp ON a.art_id=sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_saleprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_sale
ON sub_max_fromdate_sale.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_purchaseprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_purchase
ON sub_max_fromdate_purchase.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Height_sub ON ECS_Height_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Height_sub.prop_id='ECS_Height'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Width_sub ON ECS_Width_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Width_sub.prop_id='ECS_Width'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Length_sub ON ECS_Length_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Length_sub.prop_id='ECS_Length'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Depth_sub ON ECS_Depth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Depth_sub.prop_id='ECS_Depth'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Depth2_sub ON ECS_Depth2_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Depth2_sub.prop_id='ECS_Depth2'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Diameter_sub ON ECS_Diameter_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Diameter_sub.prop_id='ECS_Diameter'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Space_sub ON ECS_Space_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Space_sub.prop_id='ECS_Space'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Seatdepth_sub ON ECS_Seatdepth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Seatdepth_sub.prop_id='ECS_Seatdepth'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Seatheight_sub ON ECS_Seatheight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Seatheight_sub.prop_id='ECS_Seatheight'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Bedsize_sub ON ECS_Bedsize_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Bedsize_sub.prop_id='ECS_Bedsize'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub ON ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.prop_id='ECS_SurfaceTreat'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Weight_sub ON ECS_Weight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Weight_sub.prop_id='ECS_Weight'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Volume_sub ON ECS_Volume_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Volume_sub.prop_id='ECS_Volume'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Doors_sub ON ECS_Doors_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Doors_sub.prop_id='ECS_Doors'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Shelfs_sub ON ECS_Shelfs_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Shelfs_sub.prop_id='ECS_Shelfs'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Extensionleaves_sub ON ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.prop_id='ECS_Extensionleaves'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Dropleaves_sub ON ECS_Dropleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Dropleaves_sub.prop_id='ECS_Dropleaves'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Drawers_sub ON ECS_Drawers_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Drawers_sub.prop_id='ECS_Drawers'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Other_sub ON ECS_Other_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Other_sub.prop_id='ECS_Other'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Unit_sub ON ECS_Unit_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Unit_sub.prop_id='ECS_Unit'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Brand_sub ON ECS_Brand_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Brand_sub.prop_id='ECS_Brand'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Colour_sub ON ECS_Colour_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Colour_sub.prop_id='ECS_Colour'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_DeliveryTime_sub ON ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.prop_id='ECS_DeliveryTime'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Material_sub ON ECS_Material_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Material_sub.prop_id='ECS_Material'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Mechanism_sub ON ECS_Mechanism_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Mechanism_sub.prop_id='ECS_Mechanism'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub ON ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.prop_id='ECS_AssemblyPrice'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Assembled_sub ON ECS_Assembled_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Assembled_sub.prop_id='ECS_Assembled'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Cushion_sub ON ECS_Cushion_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Cushion_sub.prop_id='ECS_Cushion'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Manufacturer_sub ON ECS_Manufacturer_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Manufacturer_sub.prop_id='ECS_Manufacturer'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_FabricNeed_sub ON ECS_FabricNeed_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_FabricNeed_sub.prop_id='ECS_FabricNeed'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Size_sub ON ECS_Size_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Size_sub.prop_id='ECS_Size'  
WHERE a.primarysupplier='HK'
AND a.dropdate > now()
AND (a.art_id LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.primarytext LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.serie LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.parent_id LIKE '%new connection%')
AND ( sp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_sale.max_fromdate
OR sp.fromdate IS NULL)
AND ( pp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_purchase.max_fromdate
OR pp.fromdate IS NULL)
GROUP BY a.art_id,
        a.ecs_id,
        a.parent_id,
        a.primarytext,
        a.serie,
        a.receipttext,
        a.postername,
        a.posterdescription,
        a. primarysupplier,
        a.ean1,
        a.supplierarticleno,
        a.dropdate,
        a.salesinfo,
        a.packagesize,
        sp.price,
        sp.fromdate,
        sp.todate,
        pp.price,
        pp.fromdate,
        pp.todate
ORDER BY a.art_id
```

If there are not multiples then you can probably ditch the GROUP BY and the aggregate functions:-

```
SELECT a.art_id AS art_id, 
        a.ecs_id AS ecs_id, 
        a.parent_id AS parent_id, 
        a.primarytext AS primarytext, 
        a.serie AS serie, 
        a.receipttext AS receipttext,
        a.postername AS postername, 
        a.posterdescription AS posterdescription, 
        a. primarysupplier AS primarysupplier, 
        a.ean1 AS ean1, 
        a.supplierarticleno AS supplierarticleno,
        a.dropdate AS dropdate, 
        a.salesinfo AS salesinfo, 
        a.packagesize,
        sp.price AS utpris, 
        sp.fromdate AS utprisFromdate, 
        sp.todate AS utprisTodate, 
        pp.price AS innpris, 
        pp.fromdate AS innprisFromdate, 
        pp.todate AS innprisTodate, 
        ECS_Height_sub.values AS ECS_Height, 
        ECS_Width_sub.values AS ECS_Width, 
        ECS_Length_sub.values AS ECS_Length, 
        ECS_Depth_sub.values AS ECS_Depth, 
        ECS_Depth2_sub.values AS ECS_Depth2, 
        ECS_Diameter_sub.values AS ECS_Diameter, 
        ECS_Space_sub.values AS ECS_Space, 
        ECS_Seatdepth_sub.values AS ECS_Seatdepth, 
        ECS_Seatheight_sub.values AS ECS_Seatheight, 
        ECS_Bedsize_sub.values AS ECS_Bedsize, 
        ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.values AS ECS_SurfaceTreat, 
        ECS_Weight_sub.values AS ECS_Weight, 
        ECS_Volume_sub.values AS ECS_Volume, 
        ECS_Doors_sub.values AS ECS_Doors, 
        ECS_Shelfs_sub.values AS ECS_Shelfs, 
        ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.values AS ECS_Extensionleaves, 
        ECS_Dropleaves_sub.values AS ECS_Dropleaves, 
        ECS_Drawers_sub.values AS ECS_Drawers, 
        ECS_Other_sub.values AS ECS_Other, 
        ECS_Unit_sub.values AS ECS_Unit, 
        ECS_Brand_sub.values AS ECS_Brand, 
        ECS_Colour_sub.values AS ECS_Colour, 
        ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.values AS ECS_DeliveryTime, 
        ECS_Material_sub.values AS ECS_Material, 
        ECS_Mechanism_sub.values AS ECS_Mechanism, 
        ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.values AS ECS_AssemblyPrice, 
        ECS_Assembled_sub.values AS ECS_Assembled, 
        ECS_Cushion_sub.values AS ECS_Cushion, 
        ECS_Manufacturer_sub.values AS ECS_Manufacturer, 
        ECS_FabricNeed_sub.values AS ECS_FabricNeed, 
        ECS_Size_sub.values AS ECS_Size
FROM ecs_article AS a
LEFT JOIN ecs_purchaseprice pp ON a.art_id=pp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_saleprice sp ON a.art_id=sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_saleprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_sale
ON sub_max_fromdate_sale.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT article_id, max(fromdate) AS max_fromdate
    from ecs_purchaseprice
    GROUP BY article_id
) sub_max_fromdate_purchase
ON sub_max_fromdate_purchase.article_id = sp.article_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Height_sub ON ECS_Height_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Height_sub.prop_id='ECS_Height'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Width_sub ON ECS_Width_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Width_sub.prop_id='ECS_Width'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Length_sub ON ECS_Length_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Length_sub.prop_id='ECS_Length'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Depth_sub ON ECS_Depth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Depth_sub.prop_id='ECS_Depth'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Depth2_sub ON ECS_Depth2_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Depth2_sub.prop_id='ECS_Depth2'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Diameter_sub ON ECS_Diameter_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Diameter_sub.prop_id='ECS_Diameter'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Space_sub ON ECS_Space_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Space_sub.prop_id='ECS_Space'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Seatdepth_sub ON ECS_Seatdepth_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Seatdepth_sub.prop_id='ECS_Seatdepth'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Seatheight_sub ON ECS_Seatheight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Seatheight_sub.prop_id='ECS_Seatheight'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Bedsize_sub ON ECS_Bedsize_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Bedsize_sub.prop_id='ECS_Bedsize'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub ON ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_SurfaceTreat_sub.prop_id='ECS_SurfaceTreat'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Weight_sub ON ECS_Weight_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Weight_sub.prop_id='ECS_Weight'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Volume_sub ON ECS_Volume_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Volume_sub.prop_id='ECS_Volume'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Doors_sub ON ECS_Doors_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Doors_sub.prop_id='ECS_Doors'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Shelfs_sub ON ECS_Shelfs_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Shelfs_sub.prop_id='ECS_Shelfs'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Extensionleaves_sub ON ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Extensionleaves_sub.prop_id='ECS_Extensionleaves'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Dropleaves_sub ON ECS_Dropleaves_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Dropleaves_sub.prop_id='ECS_Dropleaves'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Drawers_sub ON ECS_Drawers_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Drawers_sub.prop_id='ECS_Drawers'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Other_sub ON ECS_Other_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Other_sub.prop_id='ECS_Other'   
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Unit_sub ON ECS_Unit_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Unit_sub.prop_id='ECS_Unit'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Brand_sub ON ECS_Brand_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Brand_sub.prop_id='ECS_Brand'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Colour_sub ON ECS_Colour_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Colour_sub.prop_id='ECS_Colour'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_DeliveryTime_sub ON ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_DeliveryTime_sub.prop_id='ECS_DeliveryTime'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Material_sub ON ECS_Material_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Material_sub.prop_id='ECS_Material'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Mechanism_sub ON ECS_Mechanism_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Mechanism_sub.prop_id='ECS_Mechanism'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub ON ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_AssemblyPrice_sub.prop_id='ECS_AssemblyPrice'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Assembled_sub ON ECS_Assembled_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Assembled_sub.prop_id='ECS_Assembled'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Cushion_sub ON ECS_Cushion_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Cushion_sub.prop_id='ECS_Cushion'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Manufacturer_sub ON ECS_Manufacturer_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Manufacturer_sub.prop_id='ECS_Manufacturer'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_FabricNeed_sub ON ECS_FabricNeed_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_FabricNeed_sub.prop_id='ECS_FabricNeed'  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecs_artprops ECS_Size_sub ON ECS_Size_sub.art_id = a.ecs_id AND ECS_Size_sub.prop_id='ECS_Size'  
WHERE a.primarysupplier='HK'
AND a.dropdate > now()
AND (a.art_id LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.primarytext LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.serie LIKE '%new connection%' OR a.parent_id LIKE '%new connection%')
AND ( sp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_sale.max_fromdate
OR sp.fromdate IS NULL)
AND ( pp.fromdate = sub_max_fromdate_purchase.max_fromdate
OR pp.fromdate IS NULL)
ORDER BY a.art_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have been testing the query and removing different parts to try and figure out what causes the issue. And it looks like it is the two sub queries in the WHERE statement. The sub queries in the SELECT is no problem at all. Now the big question is, why now?? This has been in production for years now.

Comment: @johnohod - Possibly the indexes in the tables used in the sub queries are not the same, or are out of date. Possibly try _OPTIMIZE TABLE ecs_purchaseprice_  and _OPTIMIZE TABLE ecs_saleprice_ to rebuild the indexes

Comment: Yes, I've been wondering if it could be an issue with the indexes. But I just tried to run optimize table, and it didn't seem to make a difference. If the indexes are damaged in any way, shouldn't I also notice that when I do an EXPLAIN?

Comment: @johnohod - I would expect it. Indexes are used depending on statistics, and those statistics get out of date. But that would probably just mean it would use the wrong index.

Comment: I edited the original question to claridy. I have added the result of EXPLAIN and removed all the ECS_xxx  queries as they run just fine and don't affect this issue. I'm left with the problem that is the left join. What I don't get is that the result of EXPLAIN looks really promising, but still the query runs like the indexes don't exist?

Comment: @johnohod - One of the joins and one of the sub queries are joining on what appear to be id fields, but in the explain are shown as having a key length of 767. That suggests possibly storing an id in a varchar field (and possibly doing conversions of data types which can be very inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the storage engine to InnoDB, deleted the indexes and created them again. And now it is back to normal. Go figure...